# BufferedReader(System.in) readLine() method returning IOException, Stream closed

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, tcpclient, tcpserver

Creating a simple chat service. I have a TCPServer program, and a TCPClient program. The programs are multithreaded, and my client program is supposed to take input from the terminal and send it to the server program. I'm having trouble with a simple while loop, and I'm at my wit's end.

I've tried BufferedReader(using .readLine() and Scanner(using .nextLine()) to try and read in messages. When I use .nextLine() I get a "java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found", and when I use .readLine() I get a "java.io.IOException: Stream closed". Here's my code (this is my thread class, within my client program):

```
private static class SendingThread extends Thread{

private Socket socket;
//  private ArrayList<Socket> socketArray;

//Constructor
SendingThread(Socket socket){
    this.socket = socket;
    //      this.socketArray = socketArray;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println("SendingThread run method executed");
        //Start timer
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        //PrintWriter to pass messages to server
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true); 
        System.out.println("PrintWriter instantiated");


        //Set up stream for keyboard entry
        BufferedReader userEntry = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("BufferedReader instantiated");

        // Get data from the user and send it to the server
        String message;
        do{
            System.out.print("Enter message: ");
            message = userEntry.readLine();
            out.println(message);
        } while (!message.equals("DONE"));

        //Stop timer
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //Variables to measure time elapsed
        long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        long milliseconds = totalTime % 1000;
        long seconds = (totalTime / 1000) % 60;
        long minutes = (totalTime / 60000) % 60;
        long hours = (totalTime / 3600000) % 60;

        //Receive final report and close connection
        System.out.println("\n*** Information received from the server ***");
        System.out.println("Length of session: " + hours + "::" + minutes + "::" + seconds + "::" + milliseconds);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            System.out.println("\n!!!!! Closing connection... !!!!!");
            socket.close(); 
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to disconnect!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

}

The problem is at the second line in my do-while loop, that's where it throws the error. It doesn't wait for my input, just terminates.

Comment: I would say it's a problem of how you are going to start your program. Some IDE's detaches the standard output (especially on Windows), so during the program run the System.in is already closed. The same if you have a GUI windows application and you are going to start this kind of app inside of it. I could be also other cases, but the problem will be similar - already closed standard input stream.

Please try to start your app outside of IDE or other apps directly from the command line/shell.